# ECTS time validity and expiration

Tags: europe, graduation

Hope this is the right place to ask this. I'm currently enrolled in a Master's Computer Science degree in Europe. I've completed most of my classes with the exception of 2 + my thesis (which would mean I'm missing about 30 ECTS from the required total of 120 ECTS for a 2 year Master program).

Due to various reasons, I was forced to keep a full time job for the past 2 years which prevented (and is still preventing me) from finishing my classes but I stayed officially enrolled in the hopes that I would find the time to finish. Next year I won't be able to re enroll with my current faculty once more due to their rules preventing students from staying too long in the same school year.

My question is: what happens to the ECTS I've accumulated thus far if I don't finish this year? I was taking into consideration further postponing school until my current job is less hectic especially since it's possible to be switching jobs at the end of the year with one in the US. This of course in the hopes that I won't be losing the 90 ECTS I have accumulated thus far.

Thank you for any information you might have on the matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this depends less on the ECTS system, and much more on your specific university. That is to say, **I assume there is no general answer to your question**. You will need to get in touch with the university.

That being said, it sounds like you want to transfer to a university in the US ("it's possible to be switching jobs at the end of the year with one in the US"). In that case the **much** larger problem will be transferring your european credits to the US institution, even if they are not expired.